# change facebook like button language without reloading page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS to build my site and I've got a language toggle on it.  I am toggling between English and French without reloading the page, just mounting a new set of reactjs components.

One of my components has a Facebook LIKE button on it, but because the facebook-jssdk is loaded independent of the component structure, it's locked in to whichever language loads first.

Is there a way for me to change the language of the loaded facebook-jssdk without reloading the page?

Comment: Can you render the like button in a separate component that takes in a prop in which you can specific the language? Then in that component, you can load the specific framework in `componentWillMount()` according to the props you pass in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@trekforever: I actually ended up doing this last night before I saw your comment!

Here's my end solution:

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    // check for a fb-like button and remove it
    // if it exists!
    if( window.FB ) {
        // remove all instances of facebook and elements
        $("#facebook-jssdk, #fb-root").remove()
        delete window.FB
    }

    // we need to use this method to let facebook-jssdk
    // know it needs to parse the xfbml after it loads
    // into our page
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        window.FB.init({
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.0'
        });
    };

    // we don't have to go through all the checks and balances that
    // come in the fb jssdk init code by default, we just got rid of them
    var fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
        js = document.createElement('script')
        js.id = 'facebook-jssdk'
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
}
```

My second language is `fr_CA` so I just replaced this line:

```
js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
```

with this:

```
js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/sdk.js'
```

and now I can re-render the component in either (or any) language and it will show me a Facebook Like button in the correct language as well!

For interest's sake, here is the same thing, but Google's Recaptcha:

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    // this is stolen directly from the facebook-jssdk
    // implementation...
    if( window.grecaptcha ){
        $("#grecaptcha-jssdk").remove()
        delete window.grecaptcha
    }

    var gjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
        js = document.createElement('script')
    js.id = 'grecpatcha-jssdk'
    js.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fr-CA'
    gjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, gjs)
}
```

It isn't named `grecaptcha-jssdk` by default, I just chose to stick with that name for consistency.

Happy i18n!